# Resolve dependencies for multiple configurations

Tags: gradle

Code speaks better than words, say I have the following build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

configurations {
    optionalDependency
}

dependencies {
    compile 'group:artifact:1.0'
    optionalDependency 'group:artifact:1.2'
}

eclipse.classpath.plusConfigurations += [configurations.optionalDependency]
```

Eclipse will now get both the 1.0 version and the 1.2 version of the artifact. Is there a way to tell gradle that I do not want both configurations, but rather resolve as though they were one?

Answer (score 0):

Just have one extend the other. If you want the `compile` configuration to include dependencies in the `optionalDependecy` configuration then simply do the following.

```
configurations {
    optionalDependency
    compile.extendsFrom optionalDependency
}
```